# How to online designer creator?

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax, jquery

http://www.tailorstore.com/pk/en/tailor-made-shirts

I want to create this kind of website where user can create shirts like this.

I am confused that is this javascript call on each design click right one shirt update?

if yes then how it is work? have they fix these small images position to long image?

like collor has fixed position on shirt (large image)

techanically i want to your suggestion how to achieve this task?

Answer (score 0):

Easy answer is to keep each category of choice, (color, type etc.) in a Session or ViewState variable, then string them all together to create an image filename and place it in an image holder. An Ajax UpdatePanel will achieve the effect created here. For example, if I click the white button then it stores

```
Session["Color"] = "white";
```

and sleeveless:

```
Session["Type"] = "sleeveless";
```

Then I can return a display image of 'white-sleeveless.jpg' by combining them.

Comment: no no i dont think  its possible see their are colors,pocket,sleves,collar and if some other then with combincation of this it will make millions of image to make first

Comment: i think there would be other solution n very smart which placing just pocket image on shirt with its proper location save in DB something i m not sure

Comment: I didn't see the other tabs initially. Then yes, same sort of deal, only there could be PNG's with transparency being shown at the right places using CSS absolute-positioning.